# Adding a LinearLayout to an existing XML

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have searched in a number of posts here for what I want to accomplish but I find no answer that I can adapt to my purpose.  (As a newbie to C# programming, I am assuming that the C# version I am using is somewhat very new and imposes many strictnesses to the syntax. But my question is not about that...)

What I am trying to do is programmatically add to an XML layout.

This is my XML:

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/daterow"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="480dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                    android:padding="0dp">
                <!--                        <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_001"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/customborder">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Slot_001"
                            android:text="00:00"
                            android:textSize="8dp"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:rotation="270"
                            android:gravity="left|center"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:maxLines="1" />
                    </LinearLayout> -->
```

My code snippet is as follows:

```
            LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.daterow);
            LinearLayout Linear1 = new LinearLayout(this);
            Linear1.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent,LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            parentLayout.AddView(Linear1);


            TextView tv = new TextView(this);

            tv.Id = i;  // i is variable in a for loop inside of which this code is.
            int qq;   //THIS LINE FOR TESTING ONLY.
            qq = 333;  //THIS LINE FOR TESTING ONLY.
            this.tv.SetText(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(this.iSlot).ToString("HH:mm"));  //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACCOMPLISH EVENTUALLY
            tv.SetText(qq);  //THIS LINE FOR TESTING ONLY. **GIVES ERROR**
            ll2.AddView(tv);  //THIS LINE FOR TESTING ONLY.
```

Ultimately, I want to programmatically achieve an XML as shown in the section "This is my XML"..

Visual Studio does not highlight any error in the syntax in the above.  But during runtime - I get the following error:

Unhandled Exception:

Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x14d

Can someone tell me what error I am committing?

In your response could you also please include which "using" I should have to use the functions that you suggest in your solution - as I am a newbie at C#.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding a LinearLayout to an existing XML

```
 LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.daterow);

 //using Android.Widget;
 Android.Widget.LinearLayout Linear1 = new Android.Widget.LinearLayout(this);

 //using Android.Views.ViewGroup;
 Linear1.LayoutParameters = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
 parentLayout.AddView(Linear1);

 Android.Widget.TextView tv = new Android.Widget.TextView(this);
 tv.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1.1).ToString("HH:mm");//THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACCOMPLISH EVENTUALLY
 Linear1.AddView(tv);  //THIS LINE FOR TESTING ONLY.
```

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x21

This happened when you use `tv.SetText(qq)` method, if you just want to set a text for `TextView`, you could use `tv.Text = qq.ToString()`.

> this.tv.SetText(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(this.iSlot).ToString("HH:mm"));  //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACCOMPLISH EVENTUALLY

Modify your code like this you could accomplish the effect :

```
tv.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1.1).ToString("HH:mm");
```

**Effect** :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting a Unhandled Exception error on this line:

parentLayout.AddView(Linear1);

Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Uttam Padukone , could you please update your code? this works fine on my side.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response - here is the code:

`LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.daterow);

 //using Android.Widget;


 Android.Widget.LinearLayout Linear1 = new Android.Widget.LinearLayout(this);

 //using Android.Views.ViewGroup;


 Linear1.LayoutParameters = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

parentLayout.AddView(Linear1);`

Comment: The logic has no problem. If possible, please share your project, or post your .axml file.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/fulldisplay"
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/datetimelogorow"
      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/datetimerow"
        <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/currentdatebox">
         <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/daterow">
         </LinearLayout>
<!-- WANT TO ADD Linear Layout here -->
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: Above is bare-bones Axml - stripped of all beautification tags....

Thank you for your interest and effort to solve my problem.

Comment: noticed this while running in step-by-step debug mode:

After executing `LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.daterow)`

parentLayout has a value of null.

Could that be the nub of the problem?

Once again - Thank you very much for your efforts to try and solve the problem.

Comment: You could edit your question to have a better format, and when you write `<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/datetimerow" .../>` in your .axml file, the `parentLayout ` should be null.

Comment: I tried that - instead of daterow, I provided the id of the first and second level Linear Layouts and that too did not work.

After execution of the LinearLayout parentLayout..... line, the variable parentLayout has a null value.

Similar questions in other forums (Xamarin for example), suggest using "var" in place of LinearLayout to make it "var parentLayout....."

That too does not work.

Comment: Could you please share a simple demo to reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to York Shen, I was able to come up with some basic principles which I used - summarized below:

1. Start with setting focus to the existing-in-axml LinearLayout under which you want to add another Linear Layout.  I used `LinearLayout dtlr = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.datetimelogorow);`  I have a LinearLayout in my axml file called datetimelogorow.
2. Next *define* your new Linear Layout thus: `Android.Widget.LinearLayout dtr = new Android.Widget.LinearLayout(this);`
3. Change all parameters as desired such as orientation, background etc using (for example) `dtr.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;`
4. Now create your LinearLayout thus `dtlr.AddView(dtr);`
5. Text view under LinearLayout can also be added similarly as in Step 2 replacing both the "LinearLayout" by "TextView" in that line.

Hope this helps.

Thanks to York Shen once again.

Uttam